# Download a XML file using TWebBrowser Delphi Component

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control

I don't know how to retrieve a XML content from TWebBrowser ActiveX component using Delphi.

If the result is a HTML, I could use:

```
 iall := (WebBrowser1.Document AS IHTMLDocument2).body;
 while iall.parentElement <> nil do
 begin
   iall := iall.parentElement;
 end;
 memo1.Text := iall.outerHTML;
```

But the URL returns a XML file and .body returns nothing.

What is the missing part for the code below??

```
var S:String;
begin
   WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://192.168.0.35:8000/api/');
   if Assigned(WebBrowser1.Document) then
   begin
     Doc := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2);
     XMLText := ???
   end;
end;
```

Remark: I could not use Indy HTTPClient component because the program will run on different proxies configurations and it will be difficult to deal with many configurations.

Comment: Using IE control for such task is really an overkill. Windows WinINet API uses proxy settings defined in OS / IE. So you can use URLDownloadToFile :

URLDownloadToFile(nil, 'http://192.168.0.35:8000/api/', 'file.xml', 0, nil);

Comment: Hi Antonio, there was no file.xml on server.  http://192.168.0.35:8000/api/ is a request that assemble the XML dinamically. Besides, I could not find the unit of URLDownloadToFile.

Comment: here is the example http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=412

Comment: it doesn't matter what server returns, URLDownloadToFile will just store that to file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work for a local XML file, and should work with a URL as well:

```
procedure TForm3.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('file:///d:/temp/TestFile.xml');
end;

procedure TForm3.WebBrowser1DocumentComplete(ASender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; const URL: OleVariant);
var
  HTML: IHtmlDocument2;
  XMLText: String;
begin
  HTML := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  XMLText := HTML.body.outerText;

  // Just for display purposes, obviously. 
  ShowMessage(XMLText);
end;
```